# React Query is not refetching data on URL change

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

This is my simle React Query function for useQuery

```
 var { isPending, isError, data } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['ordersFetch'],
        queryFn: () => fetch(FETCH_ORDERS_API + pageNumber.order).then((res) => res.json())
    })
```

I am changing the pageNumber.order by using the contextApi which results in URL change, but it is not refetching the data, how can i fetch data whenever my url changes here ?

On one screen I change the pageNumber state and then navigate to the different screen at that moment useQuery refetches the data but not when i change the state and remains on the same screen

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { MyContext } from './path/to/your/context'; // Import your context

// Assuming FETCH_ORDERS_API and pageNumber are defined somewhere above

const YourComponent = () => {
    const { pageNumber } = useContext(MyContext); // Assuming pageNumber is part of your context

    const { isPending, isError, data, refetch } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['ordersFetch', pageNumber.order], // Include pageNumber.order in queryKey
        queryFn: () => fetch(FETCH_ORDERS_API + pageNumber.order).then((res) => res.json())
    });

    // Call refetch whenever pageNumber.order changes
    React.useEffect(() => {
        refetch();
    }, [pageNumber.order]);

    return (
        // Your component JSX here
    );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use use location hooks from react-router-dom  to refetch the data when URL is changed.

```js
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const { isPending, isError, data, refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['ordersFetch', location.pathname], // Include pathname in queryKey
    queryFn: () => fetch(FETCH_ORDERS_API + location.pathname).then(res => res.json())
  });

  // Listen for changes in the location (URL) and refetch data when it changes
  useEffect(() => {
    refetch();
  }, [location.pathname]); // Trigger refetch when pathname changes

  return (
    // Your component JSX
  );
};
```